# jQuery selector formatting

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, each

I have a question that I have been dealing with for some time now.

Scenario: I have a web page that has several drop down lists (html select). I want to iterate through all drop downs using an each statement (in jQuery) and then search the options of each for a specific text element. So I have this:

```
$.each(selects, function(ind, elem){ 
    var $this = $(elem);
    $($this + ' option').filter(function() { return $(this).text() === 'some text';});
});
```

I get an error message stating: `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] option`

Does anyone know how to combine an object like `$this` plus selector text to get the result I want?

Any help would be fantastic.

Thanks,
T

Answer (score 0):

So all you need to write your JS code on Document ready event.

Following code will return the option if your searched text matched. I had add a Selected attribute itself for understanding -

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var selects = $("select");
    $(selects).each(function(index, elem){
        var searchText = "c";
        if($(elem).find('option[value="'+searchText+'"]').length > 0){
            var searchResultElem = $(elem).find('option[value="'+searchText+'"]');
            searchResultElem.attr('selected','selected');
            console.log(searchResultElem);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, I tried that and I get the same error message.[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rushman1/0eh9oxmk/11/)
Need to go into the console to see the error message. Thanks.

Comment: Daniel, You're code works for selecting the appropriate element. Unfortunately, it doesn't answer my question. The question was how can I concatenate a '$this' or 'elem' element with text to create a jQuery selector that won't throw an error message. i.e. (`$(elem + ' option')` would equal `$("select#selectId option")`) I appreciate the time that you took to give me working code, but I still don't know how to combine an element and text to select what I need to select. Sorry for any confusion that there may have been.